# Sort array of weight and values on basis of value and weight ratio

Tags: c++14

While solving the knapsack problem using a greedy algorithm, I need to sort the weight and values array on the basis of the values/weight ratio.

- Supposed weight = (5,6,12,9)
- Values = (5,3,4,4)

The `weight[i]` respective value of `value[i]` is given.

We have to sort weight in w/v ratio and hence value for the respective weight.

How can I solve this problem in the best possible way?

Comment: Your life would be much easier if, instead of two separate vectors, you use a single vector whose element is a structure with `weight` and `value` members.

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: best way is to use sse / avx shuffle intrinsics .So your solution will be just to use for loop.